# Backup & Restore SP Site with External Content Type to Another Site - make error

Tags: bcs, backup, restore, external-content-type, production

My site includes External Content Type (BCS) on Dev site, with List which of that type - and when 
i restore it to Prod server, the connectivity of the list, stay as previous system..! 
any way to backup and restore web application with lists of that kind, and still be able use them one another environment ?..

Answer (score 0):

Either you update the BCS before backup in source system or after restore in target system.

Alternatively you might be able to use server aliases feature of windows server. You set up your BSC source as "BCSSource" and then in server aliases you set up different server per environment to use the "BCSSource".